# How to use selected items in datatable as an array save to database all the data listed per row using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have this dilemma of mine. I need to know how to get all the data, only the selected one with check in the datatables. Then it will be save in the database as an array per row with added data like id. In my example I have not yet added the form which is the very import part of the code. Please help me with this.. I want to save the data coming from the datatable as student_ID, Inst_id, Subject_code, School_year, Semester. Let's say if there are 4 classes selected then it will save in the database as four row data that includes all the mention field above. I think this one needs Javascript but I don't have the idea yet on how to do it. I'm using laravel 5.7 by the way.

[image]

Thank you very much for your response in this question.

this is the studentcontroller for enroll student

```
public function enrollStudent(Request $request, $id=null){

        $studentDetails = Students::find($id);
        $classes = Classes::get();
        return view('admin.enrollment.enroll_student')->with(compact('classes','studentDetails'));

    }
```

this is my enroll_student.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.adminLayout.admin_design')
@section('content')
<div id="content">
   <div id="content-header">
      <div id="breadcrumb"> <a href="#" title="Go to Home" class="tip-bottom"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a> <a href="#" class="current">Tables</a> </div>
      <h1>Enrollment</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <hr>
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span12">
            <div class="widget-box">
               <div class="widget-title">
                  <span class="icon"> <i class="icon-info-sign"></i> </span>
                  <h5>Enroll Student</h5>
               </div>
               <div class="widget-content nopadding">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('admin/enroll-student/'.$studentDetails->id)}}" name="edit_student" id="edit_student" novalidate="novalidate">
                     {{csrf_field()}}
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Student Id</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="{{ $studentDetails->id}}" disabled>
                           <span class="input-group-btn" style="font-size:14px;" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;School Year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                           <input type="text" name="class_sy" id="class_sy" value="{{ $studentDetails->student_sy}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Student Number</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <input type="text" name="stud_no" id="stud_no" value="{{ $studentDetails->stud_no}}" disabled>
                           <span class="input-group-btn" style="font-size:14px;" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Semester</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                           <input type="text" name="student_sem" id="student_sy" value="{{ $studentDetails->student_sem}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="{{ $studentDetails->lastname}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="{{ $studentDetails->firstname}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Course</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                           <select name="course" id="course" style="width:220px;" selected disabled>
                           <option @if($studentDetails->course=="ABE") selected @endif value="ABE">ABE</option>
                           <option @if($studentDetails->course=="BEED") selected @endif value="BEED">BEED</option>
                           <option @if($studentDetails->course=="BSED") selected @endif value="BSED">BSED</option>
                           <option @if($studentDetails->course=="BSA") selected @endif value="BSA">BSA</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-actions">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enroll Classes on Student" class="btn btn-success">
                     </div>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-box">
               <div class="widget-title">
                  <span class="icon">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="title-checkbox" name="title-checkbox" />
                  </span>
                  <h5>Select Filtered Classes</h5>
               </div>
               <div class="widget-content nopadding">
                  <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th><i class="icon-resize-vertical"></i></th>
                           <th>ID</th>
                           <th>Inst ID</th>
                           <th>Subj ID</th>
                           <th>SubjCode</th>
                           <th>A.Y.</th>
                           <th>Sem</th>
                           <th>Start Time</th>
                           <th>End Time</th>
                           <th>Section</th>
                           <th>Days</th>
                           <th>Room</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        @foreach($classes as $class)
                        <tr class="gradeX">
                           <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                           <td>{{$class->id}}</td>
                           <td>{{$class->inst_id}}</td>
                           <td>{{$class->subj_id}}</td>
                           <td>{{$class->subj_code}}</td>
                           <td>{{$class->class_sy}}
                           <td>{{$class->class_sem}}
                           <td>{{$class->class_starttime}}    
                           <td>{{$class->class_endtime}}  
                           <td>{{$class->section}} 
                           <td>{{$class->days}}   
                           <td>{{$class->room}}                 
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: In my opinion, you do not have to use javascript. As an easy way, you can add a clue to your checkboxes, like **class_id**, post them and recognize which classes selected by the student.

Comment: That's a good idea.. Selected class id should be in array so that it can be save one time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you do not have to use javascript. As an easy way, you can add a clue to your checkboxes, like **class->id**

```
@foreach($classes as $class)
                        <tr class="gradeX">
                           <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_classes[]" value="{{ $class->id }}"></td>
....
```

In server side you just need to use `REPLACE INTO`. Thanks to laravel for  provide `updateOrCreate` which is perfect for here.

```
foreach($request->selected_classes as $selected_class){
    App\Enrollment::updateOrCreate(
        ['class_id'=> $selected_class, 'student_id'=>$student_id],
        ['update_at' => time()]
    );
}
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: i tried your answer but i encountered this. Array value is "on".. while I selected class with a value of 1,2,3 Array 
(
    [_token] => GEb2xST5x9mi9SxzIMC0IjlriTdUG2sVBAaUjwME
    [student_id] => 1
    [class_sy] => 
    [student_sem] => 
    [lastname] => DIOQUINO
    [firstname] => ZEMIRA
    [DataTables_Table_0_length] => 10
    [selected_classes] => Array
        (
            [0] => on
            [1] => on
            [2] => on
        )

)

Comment: Oh, it was my fault. put ```$class->id``` on ```value=""``` instead of ```checked```. I updated my answer.

Comment: yeah it works.. thank you very much..you solve my problem for a long time.. i just modified the server side by using  if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all() ;foreach($request->selected_classes as $selected_class){
            
            $enroll = new Grade;
            $enroll->class_id = $selected_class;
            $enroll->stud_id = $data['student_id'];
            $enroll->remarks = "Enrolled Subjects";
            $enroll->user = "Admin";
            $enroll->save();
            
        }
 I'm not familiar with updateorcreate method..